# How to create large hash of hashes with minimal code

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

I need to create a large hash of hashes with the following format, where speed and total are local variables:

```
hash_1 = {
  a: {
    category_1: {
      length: a["category_1"].length, 
      amount: category_1_a_total,
      speed: category_1_a_speed
    },
    category_2: {
      length: a["category_2"].length, 
      amount: category_2_a_total,
      speed: category_2_a_speed
    }
  },
  # ~ 10 more hashes to follow b..i
 }
```

I have the full hash template that is large and makes the code harder to read. Is there a way to iterate over each of the sub-hashes as I build `hash_1`, then pass the variables needed into each iterations of the sub-hashes?

Comment: Is this for testing? What is `category_2_a_total`? A function call?

Comment: The pattern is not clear. What is the logic that gives `"category_1"` for `:category_1` and `"category"` for `:category_2`?

Comment: Not for testing. category_2_a_total is a local variable. The intention is to pass back a lot of variables back to a parent method in a concise structure, hence the hash.

Comment: @sawa, that was a typo, I will amend. It should be category 2

Comment: Why do you use local variables in the first place? Wouldn't it be easier to keep their values in a hash (or that hash) right from the beginning?

Comment: This is the type of question where you're doing something wrong to begin with and solving it in the way you expect feels silly.

Comment: @KimmoLehto yes it does feel silly. can you elaborate on what is wrong and what best practice may be? thanks

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the following code should do what you asked. Still, all the comments saying you are doing is wrong are indeed very correct.

*I am posting the snippet for educational purposes only.*

```
b = binding
hash =
  (?a..?i).map do |key|
    [
      key.to_sym,
      (1..2).map do |i|
        [
          :"category_#{i}",
          {
            length: b.local_variable_get(key)["category_#{i}"].length,
            amount: b.local_variable_get("category_#{i}_#{key}_total"),
            speed: b.local_variable_get("category_#{i}_#{key}_speed")
          }
        ]
      end.to_h
    ]
  end.to_h
```

---

The code is untested, but it should work out of the box.

Comment: Are you sure they are instance  variables? And if so, then the arguments should begin with `"@..."`.

Comment: @sawa indeed, thank you, of course I meant `local_variable_get`.

Comment: Also note that since Ruby 2.6, you can pass the block to `to_h` and not need `map` right before your `to_h`.